# Gitlab CI doesn't show button "retry"

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

About a week ago, Gitlab ci stopped showing the “retry” button for all stages except the last one, and even then not always. How to return the “retry” button for other stages in the pipeline?
We use the management version of Gitlab ci https://gitlab.com/. We have this problem in all projects in several namespaces.

[image]

Comment: If you go into the job does it let you retry from there? I suspect it's a bug, which you could report via an issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new).

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the linked stage ?

Comment: No, the "retry" button is missing everywhere. Today I noticed that this bug appears when there is "environment:" in two or more stages, for example in build and deploy. If you leave "environment:" only in the build, then "retry" appears at both stages. But we can't remove "environment:" so we use it in every stage